# no such module '__ObjC'. Flutter Build Xcode Simulator

Tags: flutter

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

main.dart:1
Upgrading Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
Xcode build done.                                           34.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dgmjbgzqwhpnamaigfwxfxxxxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dgmjbgzqwhpnamaigfwxfloxxxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftinterface:0:0

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dgmjbgzqwhpnamaigfwxfxxxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dgmjbgzqwhpnamaigfwxflxxxxxxxBuild/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:0:0

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited

set libraries to no. update pod, change the target build, etc.

Comment: Did u get any solution?